# Can you fire off two or more functions at once from an event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, css-grid

https://jsfiddle.net/Jbautista1056/pvdq6gye/18/

I need help getting my event listener to fire on a specific function, but it doesn't seem to be changing anything. I'm working on the etch-a-sketch project and I'm trying to  update the grid-template-columns/rows based on the user input size. I'm able to create the div's `onclick` but the div's don't adhere to the grid-template-columns/rows format I'm trying to do. For example, if someone typed 4, it would show a total of 4 rows and 4 columns with the elements following that format in that container div. Right now it only creates 1 column and 1 row no matter what I input, because in my CSS file the default is `repeat(1, 1fr)` for both grid rows/columns. I added the `createGrid()` and `columnsAndRows()` functions to the event listener `onclick` in the html file, but only the `createGrid()` function actually fires.

This is the code I suspect I might be doing wrong but can't think of any other alternatives:

````js
function columnsAndRows() {
    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(sizeValue, 1fr)"
    gridContainer.style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat(sizeValue, 1fr)"
  }

function createGrid() {
    let parent = document.getElementById("tile")
    for (let i = 0; i < gridSize -1; i++) {. //gridSize is the total amount of squares need to be made
        let baby = document.createElement("div");
        baby.className = "babytiles"
        parent.before(baby)
    }
} ```

```html 
  <form id="totalGridSizeForm" > 
        <input type="number" placeholder="size" min="1" max="64" id ="size" value="" oninput="getSizeValue()">
        <input type="button" id="Submit"  value="Submit" onclick="createGrid()" onclick="columnsAndRows()" >
      </form>
````

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, an element can't have two of the same attributes, so your second `onclick` attribute is being ignored as demonstrated below:

```html
<div title="Message 1" title="Message 2">Hover over me</div>
```

While you could change your `onclick` attribute value to be:

```
<input type="button" id="Submit"  value="Submit" 
       onclick="function() { createGrid(); columnsAndRows(); }">
```

or, you could create a third function that simply calls the other two and then use that third function as the `onclick` function to call, [**inline HTML event attributes should not be used**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991). Instead, set them up in JavaScript using `.addEventListener()`, like this:

```js
document.getElementById("Submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
  function1();
  function2();
});

function function1(){ console.log("function1 fired!"); }
function function2(){ console.log("function2 fired!"); }
```

```html
<input type="button" id="Submit"  value="Submit">
```

Also (FYI), since you aren't actually using your input fields to submit data anywhere, you shouldn't be using the `form` tag or a `submit` button. Instead, just use a regular button:

```
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! I tested out simple function like alert("hello") using this and I got them both to fire. But my code for columnsAndRows doesn't fire. Is there a syntax issue im missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a handler function that calls both methods.

Not sure if it matters for your code, but you'll probably want to make it an async method as well depending on which one you want to run first.

something like this

```
async function handleOnClick() {
  await createGrid();
  await columnsAndRows();
}
```

Comment: oh woah I've never even heard of async till now.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap both of your functions inside one function. Then call that function.

```
 <script>
   function main() {
        function firstFunction() {

        }
        function secondFunction() {

        }
    }
</script>
<input type="button" id="Submit"  value="Submit" onclick="main()" />
```

or

```
<script>
   function firstFunction() {

   }
   function secondFunction() {

   }
   function main() {
        firstFunction()
        secondFunction()
    }
</script>
<input type="button" id="Submit"  value="Submit" onclick="main()" />
```

Comment: The only issue here is that it becomes difficult to call either of the nested functions independent of the other in other use cases.

Comment: Yes, that's true, you could do it the opposite way as well. Create a function that calls both functions.

Comment: I was wondering if the order that you state the function matters? Do they both technically fire at the same time or is it one after another?

Comment: @Bautista They fire in the order you list them. Only one can run at a time.